# Getting Google Maps V2 debug and production key for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, maps, android-maps-v2

I have been searching the internet for a while now for a step by step, idiot proof guide to obtain these keys for my Android application. But everywhere I look, the instructions seem to he vague or incomplete. It almost seems this is done on purpose...

So, if anyone could give me a step by step guide like open this, enter that, etc. It would be appreciated.

And for those who just want to send me to google guides, I already did that, they are useless..

P.S. I use Eclipse on Mac.

Comment: What did you try so far and in which step are you stucked?

Comment: Well, for one, the google tutorial si for Android Studio, and for now i use eclipse... So on step 1 I guess?

Comment: Did you find your debug keystore folder already, inside your android-sdk folder?

Answer (score 3):

For Debug key store:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Now For Realease key:

You need to do like this:

Create your own signing key that you will use for publishing, using Keytool : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

For getiing SHA from signed key tool use this:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html

Submit the signature to this link to get your Google Maps key :

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=fr

Export your application with your newly created key, in Eclipse : right click on your projet -> Android Tools -> Export signed application package.

Or you can download comeplete demo for this from here : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/load-googlemap_107

Be careful to keep your certificate in a safe place, because you will need it if you want to publish an update of your app on Google Play.

Comment: From generated code in Android Studio: "Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK. You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to sign the APK for publishing."